# Reordering data by manipulating column wise in Python

Tags: python-3.x, data-structures

I have data in a `csv` file as follows:

```
60,27702,1938470,13935,18513,8   
60,32424,1933740,16103,15082,11   
60,20080,1946092,9335,14970,2   
60,28236,1937936,13799,16871,6   
60,22717,1943455,10809,16726,4   

120,37702,2938470,23935,28513,8   
120,42424,2933740,26103,25082,11   
120,30080,2946092,2335,24970,2   
120,38236,2937936,23799,26871,6   
120,32717,2943455,20809,26726,4   

180,47702,3938470,33935,8513,8   
180,52424,3933740,36103,5082,11   
180,40080,3946092,3335,4970,2   
180,48236,3937936,33799,6871,6   
180,42717,3943455,30809,6726,4
```

I then used the following code to insert column heading:

```
df = pd.read_csv("contikiMAC_new_out.csv", names=['Energest','CPU','LPM','Transmit','Listen','ID'])
```

I used `df.groupby(['ID'])` to see the data in group according to column 'ID'.
The problem is the data in column 'LPM' gets reset after some time so I would like to add the previous value with the new value whenever the new value in LPM column is smaller for specific 'ID' .
I tried doing :

```
for x in df.groupby(['ID']):
  for i in df.ID:
    if (df.loc[i, 'LPM'] < df.loc[i - 1, 'LPM']):
        df.loc[i, 'LPM'] = df.loc[i, 'LPM'] + df.loc[i - 1, 'LPM']
```

But actually not getting the fruitful result I desire because it mixes with the 'LPM' value of different 'ID' and the process takes a long time. Can anyone please help me in suggesting a way to write the data group wise in a csv file based on 'ID' after performing the sum operation ?

The data structure I like to see is as follows:

```
60,27702,1938470,13935,18513,8   
120,37702,2938470,23935,28513,8    
180,47702,3938470,33935,37026,8    

60,32424,1933740,16103,15082,11    
120,42424,2933740,26103,25082,11   
180,52424,3933740,36103,30164,11   

60,20080,1946092,9335,14970,2   
120,30080,2946092,2335,24970,2   
180,40080,3946092,3335,29940,2   

60,28236,1937936,13799,16871,6   
120,38236,2937936,23799,26871,6   
180,48236,3937936,33799,33742,6   

60,22717,1943455,10809,16726,4   
120,32717,2943455,20809,26726,4   
180,42717,3943455,30809,33452,4
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem correctly, [DataFrame.shift](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) is what you're looking for.

Something like:

```
df['LPM_prev'] = df.groupby(['ID'])['LPM'].shift(1)
```

And then you can work with that column